# Groovy: Accessing Closure Object's elements

Tags: groovy

I am new to Groovy, and was wondering:

If I define a object like this:

```
 def buildParentXML(){
        def parentXMLElement = {
           ParentElement {
            CreationDate(new Date())
            out << buildChildXML()
            ChildElementFK(buildChildXML().childElement.ChildPK) //Something like this
           }
        }
      }
   def buildChildXML() {
     def childElement {
        ChildPK("12345679")
        Operator("Don't Know")
     }
  }
```

How would I access the value of `Element1` or `Element2`?

I tried

```
println obj.RootElement.Element1
println obj[RootElement].[Element1]
println obj['RootElement'].['Element1']
```

**Simple Example**

```
<SavePolicy>
<Segment>
    <IssueState>AK</IssueState>
    <OptionCode>ADD</OptionCode>
    <SegmentStatus>Aive</SegmentStatus>
    <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/17/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
    <ApplicationSignedDate>09/17/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
    <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
    <EffeiveDate>09/17/2013</EffeiveDate>
    <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
    <TerminationDate>09/17/2013</TerminationDate>
    <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
</Segment>
<Life>
    <FaceAmount>250.00</FaceAmount>
</Life>
```

Will Be converted into

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SEGRequestVO>
    <Service>Policy</Service>
    <Operation>submit</Operation>
    <Operator>N/A</Operator>
    <IgnoreEditWarningsNF/>
    <RequestParameters>
        <SubmissionType>SaveIt</SubmissionType>
        <ContraNumber/>
        <SegmentVO>
            <IssueState>AK</IssueState>
            <OptionCode>DD</OptionCode>
            <SegmentStatus>Aive</SegmentStatus>
            <ApplicationReceivedDate>09/17/2013</ApplicationReceivedDate>
            <ApplicationSignedDate>09/17/2013</ApplicationSignedDate>
            <CreationDate>09/17/2013</CreationDate>
            <EffeiveDate>09/17/2013</EffeiveDate>
            <IssueDate>09/17/2013</IssueDate>
            <TerminationDate>09/17/2013</TerminationDate>
            <RateSeriesDate>09/17/2013</RateSeriesDate>
            <ContraNumber/>
            <ProduStruureFK>01</ProduStruureFK>
            <LifeVO>
                <FaceAmount>250.00</FaceAmount>
                <LifePK>-123464646</LifePK>
                <SegmentFK/>
            </LifeVO></SegmentVO>
        </RequestParameters>
    </SEGRequestVO>
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible

Comment: Is it? That's bad. I am using it to build the layers of XML and sometimes I need to pass few values from Child XML to Parent XML.

Comment: Can you come up with a proper example of how you're doing this?  Something I can run?  You should be able to return the values you want to filter back up to the parent, but without a runnable example of what you're doing, it's hard to say...

Comment: -- I should quantify that last comment as a proper _small_ example ;-)

Comment: Does it help? in my case these child Xmls go to atleast 2-3 layers of parent child relationship.

Comment: But how are you creating the XML?  That's just closures (that won't run because of unknown function calls)...  Do you have that wrapped in something so it generates XML?

Comment: After building these closures I will finally `bind` them with `StreamingMarkupBuilder`.

Comment: And let's say If I get XML from ChildElement Closure, How would traverse the XML generated from StreamingMarkupBuilder?

Comment: It's still really hard to see what you're trying to do...  Could you come up with a small runnable example with the example XML you'd expect to see it output?

Comment: Do you have any email id which I can use to share actual code and xml?

Comment: I do, but StackOverflow (quite rightly) has a dislike of taking things "off-list", as it's not much help for people in the future :-(

Answer (score 0):

Right, I took a wild guess...is this what you mean?

```
import groovy.xml.*

def buildChildXML = {
    ChildPK("12345679")
    Operator("Don't Know")

    return "12345679"
}

def buildParentXML = {
    ParentElement {
        CreationDate(new Date())
        def pk = buildChildXML()
        ChildElementFK( pk )
    }
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind { it ->
    buildParentXML.delegate = it
    buildChildXML.delegate = it
    buildParentXML()
} )
```

That prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ParentElement>
  <CreationDate>Mon Sep 16 17:02:42 BST 2013</CreationDate>
  <ChildPK>12345679</ChildPK>
  <Operator>Don't Know</Operator>
  <ChildElementFK>12345679</ChildElementFK>
</ParentElement>
```

Comment: This is close to what I want but I didn't understand the delegate part. Would it work if parent has a PK and grand parent will have parent's PK as FK?

Comment: Going for lunch. Will be back in 30 min.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Again, I'm not sure what you mean. I suspect there's a much easier way of doing things than splitting the XML generation into loads of separate closures, indeed if the XML is a standard format, then it might be a [question of XML templating](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/text/XmlTemplateEngine.html) rather than taking the MarkupBuilder route

Comment: I know you are right. This is first pass of the translator class which is converting UIRequst xml to Legacy application's request xml. Even I am not how much this XML can change. That is why I am trying to factor it into multiple closure objects.

Comment: You might be making an unnecessary job for yourself. Also, I'm still not sure what you're trying to do (with no end to end example) ;-)

Comment: I am out of office now. Will post end to end example tomorrow morning.